# Which question should be used asking someone about his school?

Tags: grammar

Which one of the following questions should be used when one is asking someone about his school, he studied at?

> Where have you done your high school from?

or

> Where did you do your high school from?

Comment: I think you probably want to be asking your questions on the forum for [ell.SE]. You can read more about the two sites [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).

Comment: This question belongs on [ell.se].

Comment: In the UK, if the question were asked at all, it would be "Where did you go to school?" or "Which school did you attend?". But I think it would be asked *only* amongst those who obviously went to fee-paying schools. See also my comment below StoneyB's answer.

Comment: One does not “do” school.

Comment: The answer would also depend on which variety of English you speak. As far as I know, the term "high school" is part of American English. In the UK, such schools are called secondary schools. That means that the question would have to be "Where did you go to **secondary school**?".

Answer (score 3):

"Where'd you go to high school?"

Be careful not to confuse this with "Where'd you go to school?" In the US, this usually means "What *university* did  you attend?" which is for many people an index to your social, economic and intellectual "class".

In [St. Louis](http://www.stltoday.com/news/local/education/where-d-you-go-to-high-school-study-looks-into/article_cb5e17fa-5c95-55d8-af73-eae738ed84fd.html), however, it *does* in fact mean "What *high school* did you attend?", which in this city serves the same pigeonholing end.

Comment: Also, where you went to high school is almost entirely dependent on where you grew up (except for private school or large metropolitan areas with multiple public schools). And no one really cares about high school afterwards. So the natural question would be "where _do_ you go to high school?".

Comment: @Mitch Generally true, but not in St. Louis, where for a number of reasons (*e.g.*, a very large number of private and Catholic schools, urban sprawl, gentrification) your high school is taken to be as much a matter of choice as your university.

Comment: In the UK, we have *primary school* (up to age 11), *secondary school* (from age 11 to 16-18), then *college* and/or *university*. Private (fee-paying) schools are available for both primary and secondary levels. Prior to the mid-1970s, there was selective education at the secondary level according to whether you passed or failed the "11+ exam", and those who passed went to a *high school* or *grammar school*. As far as I know, the term "high school" is not now commonly used at all in the UK, and "school" would ***never*** mean "university".

Comment: @TrevorD It's pretty much the same in the US, except that many jurisdictions distinguish *elementary school* (K-6th grade), *middle* or *junior high school* (7-8) and *high school* (9-12). 'Primary' and 'secondary' tend to be professional/administrative rubrics, not colloquial.

Comment: @StoneyB So *high school* is up to age 12? What happens after that?

Comment: @TrevorD Sorry, we tend to speak in terms of 'grade' rather than 'age', because people start at different ages and occasionally skip grades or are 'kept back'. (My sister, for instance, started 1st grade at age 5, skipped her 12th-grade year of high school, and finished her B.A. at 18.) Add five or six to the grade I indicated for ages, and you'll be right 99% of the time.

Comment: Actually, people now use *grades* here, but as it's about 45 years since I left *high school* (of the *old* kind) and we didn't use grades then, I never remember what they mean! I didn't *start* at university until I was *19*, for a 3y course. I think it's still about age 18-19 that they *start* at uni here.

Comment: Trevor, grades in the UK are the results of exams. The term "high school" is not generally used. It's used in the names of some, particular schools. In general, such schools are called secondary schools.